# Not covering full screen iPhone

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div that stretches over the screen and that the user needs to click to dismiss. It works well on computer and Android phones but not on the lesser unit iPhone.

Here is the code:

```css
.hidden-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FFF228;
}
.overlay.ng-hide-add {
  transition: .8s linear all;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay.ng-hide-add-active {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div ng-if="showOverLay">
  <div class="overlay" ng-init="overlayShow()" ng-click="overlayRemove()" ng-hide="hideOverlay">
    <h1 class="header" data-translate>Welcome!</h1>
    <h2 class="header" data-translate>JADA JADA JADA <br>Click to continue</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems like its the overflow that isn't working. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `<div>` isn't closed correctly!

Comment: my bad, cut and pasted error

Comment: Would you like to create a working snippet for this?

Comment: done! added the end of div

Comment: The background makes me feel dizzy... :P

Comment: Why have you given `150%` height?

Comment: Have you tried making it `position: fixed` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using an `absolute` positioned element, I would disregard height and width entirely and stretch the image to the entirety of the page using positioning:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

---

Going a step further, you likely want the overlay to not scroll away on longer pages. For this, use `position:fixed`. This only has the disadvantage of scrolling still being enabled; so if a user scrolls, the overlay will look correct, but once they click it away, they will end up in the middle of the page. Addressing this requires a JS solution that goes beyond the scope of this question.